# Restrict user to a particular directory in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

Is there any way I can restrict a user to select files from only a particular directory in C#? It should not be allowed to browse other folders.

Comment: you can write your custom OpenFileDialog and only shows subdirectory of the folder in the dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible with the standard .NET wrappers.  Reject the path with the FileOk event.

If you can count on your program running on Vista and up then you could consider using the CommonFileDialog class in the Windows API Code Pack.  It has a FolderChanging event that can be canceled.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it from the application. It can be however done using user management on the OS.